# IsNaN shows other results

Tags: javascript, typescript, isnan

```
let args: string[] = process.argv.slice(2);
console.log(`All arguments: ${args}`);

let numbers: number[] = saveNumbers();
console.log(`All Numbers: ${numbers}`);

console.log(`1st argument < 10: ${firstNumberFullfill(numbers,x => x < 10)}`);

console.log(`1st argument > 10: ${firstNumberFullfill(numbers,x => x > 1000)}`);

console.log(`1st not numerical argument: ${firstNumberFullfill(args,x => isNaN(x))}`);

function saveNumbers():number[]{
    let nums: number[] = [];

    for(let a of args){
        let num = parseInt(a);
        if(isNaN(num) == false){
            console.log(a)
            nums.push(parseInt(a));
        }
    }
    return nums;
}

function firstNumberFullfill(array: Array<any>,checkFunc: (num: number) => boolean):number|string{
    for(let a of array){
        if(checkFunc(a)){
            return a;
        }
    }
    return "no number found";
}
```

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpwx0.png)

My IsNaN says "12ab" is a number but at the first Non-Number argument its the first non-number, i used the isNaN function twice so idk why it doesnt work

Comment: please explain the problem clearly. I didnt get u.

Comment: `parseInt('12ab') === 12`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not comparing the same values here: the first check (`saveNumbers`) tests `isNaN(parseInt("12ab"))` while the second tests `isNaN("12ab")`.

`saveNumbers` will parse "12ab" and return 12, which is a number and not `NaN`, while `isNaN("12ab")` will show that the String you pass is indeed `NaN`.